# How is PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials call registered or marked on DC?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, principalcontext

I am using `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials` method from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace to validate user credentials against Active
Directory LDAP server. Sample of code:

```
private bool CheckIfCredentialsAreValidInDomain(string pLogin, string pPassword)
{
    bool areCredentialsValidInDomain = true;
    using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        areCredentialsValidInDomain = context.ValidateCredentials(login, password);                
    }            
    return areCredentialsValidInDomain;
}
```

There is one domain and several (6 or more) DC in customer's environment. I don't pass DC name into `PrincipalContext` constructor - assuming DC Locator Service is doing its job - it is not important for me which particular DC is used from list of available DCs . Everything works great but I have have case of user who doesn't directly log on the domain (before starting application where this validanting is used) but his computer is physically connected to the customer's network.

This user's domain account has been recently disabled. Reason: he didn't log in to the domain for the last X months. But until then he was using app on daily basis so `ValidateCredentials` method was being called and returning true. But for unclear reason this action was "transaparent" for DC and this validation was not marked.

So how does `ValidateCredentials` work? Does it set LastLogon and lastLogonTimestamp user's attribute or just tells us if credentials are valid or not? Does it register any Event log entry on DC?

Comment: There is a password server that checks credentials.  If a machine is offline there is a local copy of the credential on the machine.  Also when a password is updated on the password server it can take time before the server notifies the rest of the network.  Some networks have multiple password servers and it may take up to a day to notify all the other password server when a password gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for `PrincipalContext` is available now. [`ValidateCredentials()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/Context.cs#L504) calls [`CredentialValidator.Validate()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/Context.cs#L241) (an internal class).

That eventually calls [`lockedLdapBind()`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/Context.cs#L226), which calls [`LdapConnection.Bind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.bind) with the credentials.

It does actually test the credentials against a server. So either that part of your code is not actually being run, or the account being tested isn't really disabled.

Something I noticed in your code is that you're passing the variables `login` and `password` to `ValidateCredentials`. However, the parameters for your method are called `pLogin` and `pPassword`. Is that just a typo in your question, or is that really how it is in your code? If that is accurate, then you're not actually testing the credentials passed to your method.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your answer. It was just a typo, it's correct in my code. That user account is now disabled but but the issue is that it has been disabled despite ValidateCredentials was used regularly. Now this account is disabled and ValidateCredentials works as it should work - returning false. But the question here is why this account  was regarded as unused for a long time while we (in the meantime) where (successfully) calling ValidateCredentials and user logged in into our application?

Comment: I couldn't tell you. It's hard to test now that it's not happening. Had he left the app open all that time? That could explain it.